# SWT browser print preview

Tags: java, browser, printing, swt, preview

My application is using SWT browser and I am trying to add print preview functionality.
There is no javascript to invoke print preview for particular web page opened in an SWT browser.

I found some hope with this link:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/OLEandActiveXexamplegeteventsfromIEcontrol.htm

But I am still unable to invoke print preview.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse `org.eclipse.swt.browser` package contains the Java code that creates a browser.

Either extend the existing code, or copy the code into your own Java package and make whatever changes you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply Gilbert, Can you please guide how to do this? like in which class file I have to make changes. Is it require some native OS programming ??

Comment: @user1682949: You can work with the Browser class first.  I don't know if there's any native OS code in the browser package.